# Why these two MPI-IO code are not working the same way?

Tags: fortran, mpi, mpi-io

I am learning MPI-IO and following a tutorial [(PDF download here)](http://user.cscs.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/CSCS_Application_Data/Files/Presentations/Courses_Ws_2011/Fats_Parallel_IO_Course_Jun11/MPI-IO_NS.pdf).

For one exercise, the correct code is:

```
Program MPI_IOTEST
Use MPI
Implicit None
Integer :: wsize,wrank
Integer :: ierror
Integer :: fh,offset
Call MPI_Init(ierror)
Call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,wrank,ierror)
Call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,wsize,ierror)
offset=4*wrank; ! because 4 bytes is one signed int
! --- open the MPI files using a collective call
Call MPI_File_Open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,'test.dat',MPI_MODE_RDWR+MPI_MODE_CREATE,MPI_INFO_NULL,fh,ierror);

Write(*,*)'rank',wrank


Call MPI_FILE_WRITE_AT(fh, offset, wrank,1,MPI_INTEGER,mpi_status_ignore,ierror);

Call MPI_File_close(fh,ierror)
Call MPI_Finalize(ierror)
End Program MPI_IOTEST
```

Then you just build and run it as 24 MPI tasks.
Then for validation, simply do
    od -i test/dat
You will get the result exactly the same on the tutorial, which is given below.

```
0000000           0           1           2           3
0000020           4           5           6           7
0000040           8           9          10          11
0000060          12          13          14          15
0000100          16          17          18          19
0000120          20          21          22          23
0000140
```

But if I change **1** to **num**:

```
Call MPI_FILE_WRITE_AT(fh, offset, wrank,1,MPI_INTEGER,mpi_status_ignore,ierror);
```

into

```
Call MPI_FILE_WRITE_AT(fh, offset, wrank,num,MPI_INTEGER,mpi_status_ignore,ierror);
```

and before that define

```
integer :: num
num=1
```

After rm test.dat, then re-build the file and run it, you will get:

```
0000000           0           0           0           0
*
```

Answer (score 4):

Your error is not actually in the specification or use of `num` but rather in the specification of `offset`.

If you read the [man-page](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_File_write_at.html) of `MPI_File_write_at`, you have to specify the offset as MPI_Offset kind.

So if you change your program to use:

```
integer(kind=MPI_OFFSET_KIND) :: offset
```

It works fine.

Did you not notice the size of the test.dat file generated?

Comment: But it is writing the test.dat in non-human readable language? seems to be binary